# ¿Como puedo restar en un Switch de Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

```
var i = 20; //esta es la cantidad que quiero restar punto por punto o sumar punto por punto
switch (true) {
    case actualElemento > 1 && actualElemento <= 50:
        var iresta = i - 1;
        document.getElementById("idtir0").textContent = "PERDISTE UN PUNTO";
        document.getElementById("punt0").textContent = "PUNTOS " + iresta;
        break;
    case actualElemento > 50 && actualElemento <= 100:
        var isuma = i + 1;
        document.getElementById("idtir0").textContent = "GANASTE UN PUNTO ";
        document.getElementById("punt0").textContent = "PUNTOS " + isuma;
        break;
```

Lo que quiero es ir restando punto por punto e ir bajando o sumando punto por punto e ir subiendo.

Comment: ¿que es actualElemento?  Pon todo el código para que podamos reproducir tu problema, que por cierto, no se cual es aún pues solo dices lo que quieres pero no explicas lo que ocurre ni si estás en un bucle ni que son esos elementos HTML que no vemos ni que error te da tu código actual.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente, eso mas que un switch, es un if.

```
var i = 20;
if(actualElemento > 1 && actualElemento <= 50){
    var iresta = i - 1;
    document.getElementById("idtir0").textContent = "PERDISTE UN PUNTO";
    document.getElementById("punt0").textContent = "PUNTOS " + iresta;
}else if(actualElemento > 50 && actualElemento <= 100){
    var isuma = i + 1;
    document.getElementById("idtir0").textContent = "GANASTE UN PUNTO ";
    document.getElementById("punt0").textContent = "PUNTOS " + isuma;
}
```

porque realmente el problema es que el switch solo recibe valores fijos, es decir, le pasamos la variable en el switch y luego los posibles valores en cada caso. pero ya para compara se usa mas el if.

Comment: Si te fijas en el switch de la pregunta, te deberías dar cuenta del error de lo que dices del switch al afirmar que ***el switch solo recibe valores fijos***. Un switch puede funcionar para expresiones booleanas perfectamente y de forma mejor estructurada que ir haciendo **else if** continuamente, al menos visualmente y en mi modesta opinión. Tu respuesta no satisface la pregunta del OP (Original Poster), pues se limita tan solo ha cambiar el switch por if, sin variar el resultado final, y es por ello que puede tener votos negativos al no ser útil, lo siento.